# Asterisk queue context not working

Tags: queue, asterisk

I'm implementing a callback service for Asterisk queues.
The idea is to place all incoming calls on a queue. A message is played back, letting callers know that they can either wait in line until an agent becomes available or they can press '2', hangup, and have the agent call them back as soon as possible.

I defined a context for the inbound queue in *queues.conf* as such:

```
[qIngresoCC]
...
context=qIngresoCC-callback
...
```

and defined the corresponding entries in *extensions.conf*:

```
[qIngresoCC-callback]
exten = > 2,1,NoOp("El cliente ${CALLERID(all)} solicita CallBack")
  same => n,AGI(add_channel_to_callback.php)
  same => n,Playback(goodbye_for_the_best)
  same => n,Hangup()
```

An incoming call is correctly sent to the queue, the announcements are played back, but when pressing '2', the call is not sent to the qIngresoCC-callback context.

DTMF logging is enabled, and I can see Asterisk receiving it, but it simply won't jump to the specified context.

```
[Jul  4 10:45:47] DTMF[84833][C-0000014d]: channel.c:4017 __ast_read: DTMF end '2' received on SIP/axtel-rappi-0000027b, duration 0 ms
[Jul  4 10:45:47] DTMF[84833][C-0000014d]: channel.c:4076 __ast_read: DTMF end accepted without begin '2' on SIP/axtel-rappi-0000027b
[Jul  4 10:45:47] DTMF[84833][C-0000014d]: channel.c:4087 __ast_read: DTMF end passthrough '2' on SIP/axtel-rappi-0000027b
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to specify:
I'm using Asterisk 13.14.0 compiled from source (by Portage) on Gentoo, with support (USE flags) for `caps, curl, http, iconv, odbc, pjproject, postgres, samples, srtp`.

I'm not using freepbx nor any other GUI. Everything is configured manually through the .conf files.

The only tuning of the source I did was changing `channel.h` from `#define AST_MAX_ACCOUNT_CODE 20` to `#define AST_MAX_ACCOUNT_CODE 256` to be able to use  longer account codes.

Comment: Check freepbx source code in case of breakout ivr.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tetll. I'm not using freepbx. I use plain Asterisk compiled from source. I've updated the OP.

Comment: yes, but it WORKING in freepbx, so no problem check in dialplan HOW. There are no AGI in queue module login in freepbx, pure dialplan.

Comment: So... I tried your suggestion. I checked on a working configuration in freepbx, but nothing special nor different is done. The queue has a context defined, and when a call lands on that queue, pressing _any_ digit correctly sends the call to the breakout context. There's nothing more to it, and nothing substantially different from my config. Even if I copy & paste those conf lines it still does not work.

Comment: So what you suggest? Test your config myself or what? That feature definitly working as described.

Comment: Well, that's the thing: in my setup it is _definitely_ not working as it's supposed to. Perhaps someone (not necessarily you) has had this issue before, with a certain combo of version, OS, or whatever, and can shed some light for me.

Also, as a side note: There's no need to be rude. I'm simply asking for help with something I haven't been able to solve by myself. I you can't or just don't want to, that's ok too.

Answer (score 2):

The digit pressed must match the extension level in the context: for example if you have context=queue_out in your queues.conf and let's say your recording says "Press 5 to leave a voicemail (periodic announcement): extensions.conf would have the following

```
[queue_out]
exten => 5,1,Voicemail(123@default)
exten => 5,n,Hangup()
```

I had the same problem btw.